# how to properly model this business with ruby models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm trying to figure out how to properly model this app I want to build. The app is a customer service communication tool. A customer service rep will have multiple customers he/she is communicating with but a customer will only be communication with one customer service rep.

There are Users (customer service rep), Customers, and a User has_many customers and a customer belongs_to a User.

So, I also need a Message model. The Message model should have a user_id, a customer_id, the message_text, a sent_from (user or customer), and sent_to (user or customer).

So, a User has_many :messages and a Customer has_many :messages. And a message belongs_to a User and a Customer. However, I'm not sure if I need a has_many :through association (let's say Conversation) or not. Would my current setup allow for everything I need? Or do I need another model to encapsulate the entire conversation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the conversation between the user and customer is just one thread of messages, then you don't need a Conversation model. However, if it's multiple threads (think Gmail style) then you have two options:

1. Add a conversation model
2. Introduce parent/child relation between messages